# Can I use the DynamoDB .NET Object Persistence Model when I have a Global Secondary Index?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in Dynamo with a hash & range index plus a secondary global index with just a hash.  If I try to Query or Save an object I get the following error:

> Number of hash keys on table *TableName* does not match number of hash keys on type *ObjectModelType*

(Replacing *TableName* and *ObjectModelType* with the actual table and model type)

I have the hash properties (both the primary and secondary) decorated with `DynamoDBHashKey`

[Googling the error turns up exactly zero results](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22Number%20of%20hash%20keys%20on%20table%22%20%20%22does%20not%20match%20number%20of%20hash%20keys%20on%20type%22&oq=%22Number%20of%20hash%20keys%20on%20table%22%20%20%22does%20not%20match%20number%20of%20hash%20keys%20on%20type%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.12194j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

**Update:** Ok, so not exactly zero, obviously it now returns *this question!*

**Update the second:** I've tried using the [helper API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ItemCRUDDotNetHelperAPI.html) & it works just fine, so I am assuming at this point that the Object Persistence Model doesn't support Global Secondary Indexes

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace for this error? Also, what version of the .NET AWS SDK are you using? GSI support only exists in version 2.0.5 and greater.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and found *FromQuery* worked, although *QueryFilter* is actually from the *DocumentModel* namespace:

```
var queryFilter = new QueryFilter(SecondaryIndexHashKeyColumn, QueryOperator.Equal, "xxxx");
queryFilter.AddCondition(SecondaryIndexRangeKeyColumn, QueryOperator.LessThan, DateTime.Today);
var items = context.FromQuery<MyItem>(new QueryOperationConfig { IndexName = SecondaryIndexName, Filter = queryFilter }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Brendon for that tip! I was able to adapt it to get deserialization of a multiple result set.

```
var queryFilter = new QueryFilter(indexedColumnName, QueryOperator.Equal, targetValue);
Table table = Table.LoadTable(client, Configuration.Instance.DynamoTable);
var search = table.Query(new QueryOperationConfig { IndexName = indexName, Filter = queryFilter });

List<MyObject> objects = new List<MyObject>();
List<Document> documentSet = new List<Document>();
do
{
    documentSet = search.GetNextSetAsync().Result;
    foreach (var document in documentSet)
    {
        var record = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(document.ToJson());
        objects .Add(record);
    }
} while (!search.IsDone);
```

Thanks x1000!! :)